# ¿como remplazar el caracter � (\uFFFD) por la ñ al mostrar valores de la BBDD SQL?

Tags: php

Se me presentó este problema, ya que en un `<select></select>` tengo un `foreach` que muestra varios `<option></option>.` , La cuestión es que me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé con

```
preg_replace('@\x{FFFD}@u', "Ñ", $dataCombobox['nombre_oficina'])";
```

Y sale en la etiqueta `<option>` vacío (sin `strings` alguno) y las demás etiquetas se muestra su nombre normalmente.

Comment: Prueba haciendo utf8_encode($dataCombobox['nombre_oficina'])

Comment: @CamiloVasquez 
Eres el mejor, simple y sencillo. Ya el problemita, está resuelto, muchas gracias.

Comment: @AngelZambrano me alegra que te sirviera, tu pregunta ha sido marcada como duplicada te invito a eliminarla y a que leas detenidamente la respuesta aceptada de la pregunta que te pasa Dev. Joel, saludos!